# Node js oracle module: the console log statement not working when select query is executed

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I have installed the node-oracle module and have connected to an oracle database successfully. But, I have a problem when I execute a select query. My code is below (the file name is tests-connection.js):

```
    var oracle = require('./');

    var connectData = {
        hostname: "myhost",
        port: 1521,
        database: "mydb", // System ID (SID)
        user: "usertest",
        password: "mypass"
    }
    oracle.connect(connectData, function(err, connection) {
        if (err) { console.log("Error connecting to db:", err); return; }

        connection.execute("SELECT systimestamp FROM DUAL", [], function(err, results) {

            if (err) { console.log("Error executing query:", err); return; }

            console.log(results); //This statement's not working
            connection.close(); // call only when query is finished executing
        });

    });
```

The output in Node.js command prompt (nothing):

```
    C:\xampp\htdocs\motcua.dev\public\socket.io\node_modules\oracle>node tests-connection
    C:\xampp\htdocs\motcua.dev\public\socket.io\node_modules\oracle>
```

I have tried to update a record and it works, but when I execute a select query I do not see any output in the console log statement. The terminal is empty until the code that is executing is finished.

How can one fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show us the context from where're you calling this `connection.execute` function? If you run that same function passing `SELECT systimestamp FROM dual`, does it return anything?

Comment: I have created a file that called tests-connection.js below node-oracle module. I'm calling `connection.execute` function inside the `oracle.connect` function.

Comment: I also tried to run this function passing `SELECT systimestamp FROM dual` and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Are you checking for errors just after the `oracle.connect` call? The user you're using to connect to this databese have the proper permissions to execute a `select` statement? Please, uptade your question with more of your code.

Comment: I have just edited my question. The full content of tests-connection.js file has added. The user that i'm using has proper permissions to execute `SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, UPDATE` statements.

Comment: could you check the `console.log(typeof results)` or `console.log(results.rows)` and share the output.